# Get Value from a cell on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do what I think is something simple and looks right.  What I'm trying to do is pull a value from a cell on a worksheet that is in the current workbook.  However, every time I run the code I get the following error: Run-time error'g':  Subscript out of range.  Below is the listed code that I'm using.

```
Damp_DL_Height = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DampType").Cells(3, 3).Value
```

I've got the variable defined as Double.  DampType is equal to the name of the sheet that I'm trying to pull the cell data from.  Should I be using some other type of command to get the value?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is DampType a variable?

Comment: Damptype is defined as a String Variable.  Would look something like this: CD60

Comment: Thank you.  Taking out the quotation marks worked.

Answer (score 11):

Since `DampType` is a string variable, it doesn't need quotation marks -

```
Damp_DL_Height = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DampType).Cells(3, 3).Value
```